# ASP.NET Button causes a postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have an asp.net button on the page. I am trying to do this:

```
    $("#btn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('hi');
    }
```

But the alert never shows up. I have to use an ASP.NET button only and not a HTML one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you reference the ClientID of the button, not the "normal" ID.

```
$("#<%= MyControl.ClientID %>").click(function() {
   alert(...);
   return false;
}
```

Also make sure this is inside a document.ready() handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%= MyControl.ClientID %>").click(function() {
       alert(...);
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I still do not get the alert()..i have done exactly as you told

Answer (score 1):

Try to have the method return false as well and in your buttons onclick you add the javascript. Like this:

```
$("#btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
    return false;
}
```

or add it as an onclientclick function like this:

```
 function ClickFunction() {
     alert('hi');
     return false;
 }

 <asp:Button OnClientClick="return Clickfunction();" />
```

Comment: i do not want to use the onclientclick. It does not work even after using the precentdefault and return false

Comment: What you could do if you do not need the server functionality of the button is remove the runat="server" attribute. But then I would recommend using a standard <input type="button" /> instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got the answer over here

[Using jQuery to Prevent ASP.NET Server Side Events from Occuring](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/05/using-jquery-to-prevent-aspnet-server.html)

I was missing the `$(document).ready(function()` . So silly of me!